# writing from two engines into same file

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

Hello I have a cvs file that is read, and calls and API to get information and then is written into a file as shown below. Currently with only one Delimited Record class.

```
        public class EE
        {
            [FieldOrder(1)]
            public string Name;
            [FieldOrder(2)]
            public string Description;
            [FieldOrder(3)]
         }


....creating engine....

  using (enginev2.BeginWriteFile(@"C:\Update\" + fileName))
                {
                    foreach (EEEEoutput in arrayEmployees)
                    {
                        enginev2.WriteNext(EEoutput);
                    }

            }
```

Now I have to create another delimited record as it has a different structure, but I need it to write into that same file. Meaning having two different filehelpers engines write one after another to the same file. is this possible?

I have simplified the amount of fields for sake of example. They are both very different and have a lot of fields.

```
public class EETravel
        {
            [FieldOrder(1)]
            public string TrxType;
            [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
            [FieldOrder(2)]
            public string EmployeeID;
    }

  using (engineTravel.BeginWriteFile(@"C:\Update\" + fileName))
                {
                    foreach (Employees_Travel EEtravel in arrayTravel)
                    {
                        engineTravel.WriteNext(EEtravel);
                    }

                }
```

when I have the code above, it completely over rides what the first engine wrote. So My question is, how do I get the second engine to pick up where the first engine left off, and then update the file?

thank you

Comment: First, if this is in multithreaded code you'll want to do some locking around the writing. Second, open the file for append. Third, seek to the end of the file before writing to maintain other code's updates.

Comment: thank you I used BeginAppendToFile and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
 using (engineTravel.BeginAppendToFile(@"C:\Update\" + fileName))
                {
                    foreach (EETravel EEtravel in arrayTravel)
                    {
                        engineTravel.WriteNext(EEtravel);
                    }

                }
```

used `.BeginAppendToFile` in the second engine and it picked up where the other engine left off.